# Where is the code for "{{store url="example/example"}}

Tags: magento-1.8, cms, template-directive

I would like to know how Magento converts `{{store url="example/example"}}` into `http://www.example.com/example/example/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::storeDirective()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php#L298-327).

Don't be confused by the class name, `Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter` extends from it and the basic functionality of these *directives*<sup>1</sup> is in the base class `Varien_Filter_Template`. Not the best class hierarchy, I know.

Look at the [`filter()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php#L131-171) method in `Varien_Filter_Template`, this is what is called when a CMS page or email template is rendered.

---

<sup>1) all the `{{stuff in curly brackets}}`</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::storeDirective
```

Which is called from `Varien_Filter_Template::filter` and specifically the section below which matches the `CONSTRUCTION_PATTERN` (stuff in double curly braces).

Then strips out the type e.g `{{store url=""}}` would be `store` this type is then prefixed to the word 'Directive' to form the callback method name into which the matched string is passed.

`$callback = array($this, $construction[1].'Directive');`

```
 if(preg_match_all(self::CONSTRUCTION_PATTERN, $value, $constructions, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
                foreach($constructions as $index=>$construction) {
                    ...
                    $callback = array($this, $construction[1].'Directive');
                    ...
                        $replacedValue = call_user_func($callback, $construction);
                    ...
                    $value = str_replace($construction[0], $replacedValue, $value);
                }
            }
```