# APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables

Tags: admin, patches, supee-6788, template-directive, directive-whitelist

APPSEC-1057 (part of SUPEE-6788) states

> Magento now includes a whitelist of allowed blocks or directives. If a module or anyone uses variables like `{{config path=”web/unsecure/base_url”}}` and
>   `{{block type=rss/order_new}}` in CMS pages or emails, and the directives are not on this list, you will need to add them with your database installation script.
>
> Extensions or custom code that handles content (like blog extensions) might be affected. If your code uses some config variables or blocks, you need to create a data update script that adds variables or blocks to the white list tables:

How do you whitelist custom variables and blocks?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, you can manually add blocks and variables to the white lists under *System > Permissions > Variables* and *System > Permissions > Blocks*. The codes you add there are in the form `web/unsecure/base_url` (config path) or `rss/order_new` (block class alias).

## Original answer

My upgrade script looks like this:

```
/*
 * Make sure the upgrade is not performed on installations without the tables
 * (i.e. unpatched shops).
 */
$adminVersion = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Mage_Admin')->version;
if (version_compare($adminVersion, '1.6.1.2', '>=')) {

    $blockNames = array(
        'cms/block',
        'catalog/product_list',
        'germany/impressum',
        'page/html',
        'magesetup/imprint_field',
        'magesetup/imprint_content'
    );
    foreach ($blockNames as $blockName) {
        $whitelistBlock = Mage::getModel('admin/block')->load($blockName, 'block_name');
        $whitelistBlock->setData('block_name', $blockName);
        $whitelistBlock->setData('is_allowed', 1);
        $whitelistBlock->save();
    }

    $variableNames = array(
        'design/email/logo_alt',
        'design/email/logo_width',
        'design/email/logo_height',
    );

    foreach ($variableNames as $variableName) {
        $whitelistVar = Mage::getModel('admin/variable')->load($variableName, 'variable_name');
        $whitelistVar->setData('variable_name', $variableName);
        $whitelistVar->setData('is_allowed', 1);
        $whitelistVar->save();
    }
}
```

Replace `$blockNames` and `$variableNames` with your own. The following tool helps to find used variables and blocks: https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons

Loading the variables/blocks first makes sure that you don't try to insert duplicates (this would crash the script). This happened to me because the script showed me variables "trans_email/ident_general/email" and "trans_email/ident_support/email" which are already whitelisted in the final patch release.

### How to use the upgrade script

Place it in a custom module as data upgrade script (data upgrade scripts are run after normal upgrade script, this ensures that the tables already exist). If you don't have a module yet that you use for config updates, create it like this:

#### app/etc/modules/Project_Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Project_Config>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Project_Config>
    </modules>
</config>
```

#### app/code/local/Project/Config/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Project_Config>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Project_Config>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <project_config>
                <setup>
                    <module>Project_Config</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </project_config>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

#### app/code/local/Project/Config/data/project_config/data-install-0.1.0.php

*(as above)*

Comment: This worked well for my custom blocks. I don't fully understand how the variable whitelist works. Variables in my existing custom modules do not appear in the whitelist, but are working.

Comment: the blocks show, but the db isn't changed. weird

Comment: just to clarify my comment above regarding variables, are we are talking about whitelisting variables called in cms or locale files i.e. email templates using {config path= and not custom module variables accessed in PHP with Mage::getStoreConfig('my_var') ? So far the tools have found blocks that are not whitelisted, but no variables.

Comment: only `{{config}}` directives need whitelisting. The code is intended for projects, not for extensions, so I assume a patched shop, but extensions should check the Magento version (or better, check if the tables exist)

Comment: @fschmengler will this module run only on versions higher than 1.9 ? or also 1.7?

Comment: on all versions if SUPEE-6788 is applied

Comment: @fschmengler Many people will use this script as is. Why don't you improve it and add checking for duplicates? It would be perfect after that. Also, will this script crash if SUPEE-6788 was not applied (e.g. on Magento versions earlier than 1.9.2.2)?

Comment: Yes, it would crash. I added a check for the new tables that makes the script do nothing gracefully if the tables are missing

Comment: Updated again with a nicer check thanks to @mam08ixo https://gist.github.com/mam08ixo/3937df764da7a6816a1d

Comment: @fschmengler Isn't it necessary to add `$installer = $this; $installer->startSetup();` at the beginning of this script and `$installer->endSetup();` at the end? If not, why it isn't required in this case?

Comment: @zitix No it is not required. `startSetup()` and `endSetup()` disable foreign key checks, so they are only necessary if you create or modify tables with foreign keys. I don't need anything else from the setup class, so I omitted `$installer = $this` as well.

Comment: @fschmengler So it will not do any harm if I insert your script between `startSetup()` and `endSetup()` to my existing setup file (which already contains some other code)?

Comment: Except that you should consider changing the `return` to something else then. I'll update again with a safer version.

Comment: Very good solution to the problem, +1 for the link to the peters tool that finds all variables and blocks used in a page that do not comply with the patch https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons

Answer (score 16):

You can  add them manually in the Magento backend under ***System > Permissions > Variables*** and ***System > Permissions > Blocks*** once Magento 1.9.2.2 is installed.

Plugins that use custom variables of blocks will need to add a data upgrade script with code similar as shown below.

```
if (Mage::getModel('admin/block')) {

    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $connection = $installer->getConnection();

    $installer->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
        $installer->getTable('admin/permission_block'),
        array(
            array('block_name' => 'flexslider/view', 'is_allowed' => 1),
        )
    );

    $installer->endSetup();

}
```

Comment: This will only work for community edition, I would add the check on CE and EE:
if ((Mage::getEdition()==Mage::EDITION_COMMUNITY && version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.9.2.2', '>=')) ||
(Mage::getEdition()==Mage::EDITION_ENTERPRISE && version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.14.2.2', '>=')) {

Comment: as @DmitryFurs stated there better make your check *if feature exist* by checing the tables or existance of configuration fields but not on version

Comment: Good point Vladimir and Anton. I tried using this if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($installer->getTable('admin/permission_block'))) { ... } but it results in an error . Any idea on how to poperly check if the table exists and do nothing if it doesnt?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can use if (Mage::getModel('admin/block')) { ... }

Answer (score 5):

You can find there are new tables after `SUPEE-6788` patch has been installed

`permission_variable`

`permission_block`

And you can add some config variables or blocks to these whitelist tables.