# Patch SUPEE-6788 and catalog/navigation blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, patches, ce-1.9.2.1, supee-6788

I applied the patch SUPEE-6788 from 1.9.2.1 and had a issue with a catalog/navigation block type.

I have this in a CMS static block:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="categoryLandingPage" template="catalog/category/landing.phtml"}}
```

And it no longer shows that block; no errors in the log, or var/report folder.

I have other static blocks with the block type of `core/template` and they are working fine. Right now, I think it has something to do with the APPSEC-1063 section of the patch.

Answer (score 1):

The block likely uses a non-standard variable, which will need to be added to the whitelist.  [See this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87897#87897) for steps on doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely will have to add a new block type to the 'safe' blocks that Magento understands. The most easy way to do this, is by navigating to:

```
System -> Permissions -> Blocks
```

in the Magento backend. You would then create a new block by clicking the button. Set the 'Block Name' to:

```
catalog/navigation
```

And allow it. This should do the trick.

Alternatively, you could lookup the tables permissions_blocks using your favorite MySQL viewer/editor, such as PHPMyAdmin, and insert a new entry with the above value.