# Have problem to display blocks after applied SUPEE-6788 ,

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-6788

After I applied the security patch SUPEE-6788 , some of the "non-static" blocks( like newsletter signup form and blocks that call functions) disappeared and I have tried empty cache many times. Anyone knows what is the cause? I use Magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: Please look through the already posted questions on this forum. This question is already posted several times

Answer (score 1):

The blocks likely use non-standard variables, which will need to be added to the whitelist.  [See this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87897#87897) for steps on doing so.