# Magento 1.9.0.1 + Patch SUPEE-6788 breaks custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, ce-1.9.0.1, patches, supee-6788

I have tried to apply the new patch SUPEE-6788 on my website which was successful without any errors.

After that I recompiled Magento using Configuration > tools > compilation. After doing that my custom theme layout broke. It is missing some blocks etc.

Any suggestions on this please?

Comment: See this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87897#87897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This patch enforces a block whitelist.  You can add your blocks in the admin section under `System -> Permissions -> Blocks`, or via setup scripts adding to the `permission_block` table.

Answer (score 1):

```
System > Permissions > Blocks
Add New Block
Block Name: cms/block
Is Allowed : Yes
```

after the update you need to white-list the blocks and clear cache