# when apply SUPEE-6788 my home page goes blank

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-6788

When I apply `PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.0.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-59-04.sh`
in my magento 1.9.0.0 my home page goes blank.

My 1column.phtml shows on frontend:

```
<div class="main container show-bg">
         <div class="preface grid-full in-col1"></div>
         <div class="col-main grid-full in-col1"></div>
         <div class="postscript grid-full in-col1"></div>
</div>
```

when I reverse apply the patch, the website shows back.

Comment: Related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables

Answer (score 2):

Did you whitelists the blocks ?
Follow these steps to white-list it

```
 1.System > Permissions > Blocks

 2. Add New Block
    Block Name: cms/block
    Is Allowed : Yes
```

after the update you need to white-list the blocks and clear cache

Answer (score 1):

Run the PHP script here https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox and in the report WHITELIST as said above all the blocks it identifies.

You will then be good to go.

Steve