# Has Magento newsletter block in 1.9.2.2 changed?

Tags: newsletter, ce-1.9.2.2

I updated to 1.9.2.2. from 1.9.1. Now i do not see the newsletter subscription form in footer anymore. In the block i use this:`{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}`Has this changed in 1.9.2? The text that i also added in that block does appear in footer, just not the form. I use Magemonkey and that is updated to latest version also, but no difference.

SOLVED: In the Magento backend under "System > Permissions > Variables" and "System > Permissions > Blocks" i added newsletter-en and refreshed cache... after that it was visible again in store.

Comment: Please accept my answer or post your solution and self-accept it, so this question will be marked as closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Magento backend "*System > Permissions > Variables" and "System > Permissions > Blocks*"

Add `newsletter/subscribe` and refreshed cache.

**More info:**

There is a new check on the template directive, see   *Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::blockDirective()* line 176

```
   if ($this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
        $type = $blockParameters['type'];
        $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `newsletter/subscribe` block is not on the default whitelist that was introduced with the latest patch and version 1.9.2.2; this means you can not call it from a cms block if you don't add it to the whitelist manually before.

See here how to add it:
[APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87897)

Comment: i can't seem to figure this one out... completely stuck

Comment: are you still stuck? if so, where?