# Getting the category id does not work in 1.9.2.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, cache

I have a static block which looks like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/subcategory_listing.phtml"}}
```

I am using this block for all my categories in the `Display settings` tab. Now in the `subcategory_listing.phtml` I am trying to get the id of the current category, like this:

```
$catId = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
```

As it seems, that is being cached, it always returns the id of the category I opened first after cleaning the cache. After that, it always returns the same category id.

Disabling the `Blocks HTML output` cache makes it work but I hope there is another solution. It worked with Magento 1.8.x.

I also added `catalog/navigation` to my `permission_block` table which did not help.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

The `catalog/navigation` block is of course cached for the whole page and not separately for each category. Hence, this caching behaviour is logical. To solve this, you could add the category ID to the cache tags of the `catalog/navigation` block. Then, the block would be cached separately for each category.

But in your case, it may be enough to simply use `Mage::registry('current_category')` instead of your `$this->getCurrentCategory()`.

Comment: Good cache @simon...

Answer (score 0):

First,you need follow the : [@schmengler answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87974/4564)

For you case,you need to add `catalog/navigation` to `$blockNames` .

```
$blockNames = array(
        'cms/block',
        'catalog/product_list',
        'germany/impressum',
        'page/html',
        'magesetup/imprint_field',
        'magesetup/imprint_content',
    'catalog/navigation'
    );
```

Comment: I aleady added catalog/navigation to permission_blocks manually, but this did not help. It must be something else...ideas?