# since SUPEE-6788 shop name is missing in Emails

Tags: email-templates, patches, supee-6788, template-directive

hi we have an email template for our orders with this subject

```
{{block type="imprint/field" value="shop_name"}}: Rechnung Nr. # {{var invoice.increment_id}} für Bestellung Nr. # {{var order.increment_id}}
```

since SUPEE-6788 the shop name is not printed, has anyone else the Problem?

The shop name under System->Configuration->General->Imprint->"Shop Name" is still filled for all stores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add block types used in `{{block}}` directives to the new block whitelist (in your case: `imprint/field`). You find the whitelist in *System > Configuration > Permissions > Blocks*.

More info: [APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables)

Comment: wow does this mean i have to search through my whole shop and whitelist all used blocks?

Comment: @wutzebaer yes but not manually. There are tools for it: https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons or https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox