# Static block not working in categories page

Tags: category, blocks, patches, static-block, ce-1.9.1.1

I added security patches a while ago, not sure if this is was the trouble maker or not.

I have a page that should show all the categories as thumbs and it is broken.
It is configured via template that has built in option to show any static block assigned(venusthemes) and if I assign an other block from admin it will work fine, but if I put my categories block it will not.

If I go cms-> static blocks and open my block I have
`{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/categories.phtml"}}`

and this is what is not working, if I type random text then I can see it, but with block I get blank page
I went to system -> permissions -> blocks and added catalog/navigation to allowed list and cleared my cache which is disabled even now but no use :(

And the same code I am using in /categories.phtml I am using also in the frontpage and it works....oh why is this like that??

Comment: Do you have an unmodified magento code to test it? I can try it on mine if not. Check to see if you have a module that is rewriting any blocks or helpers from catalog that may be interfering. I will post my results shortly.

Comment: I am pretty sure your theme is broken after the updated patches.

Answer (score 3):

The latest security patch added a whitelist for blocks that are allowed to be used in the CMS with the `{{block}}` directive.

Navigate to System > Permissions > Blocks and add the block type `catalog/navigation` to the whitelist.

See also: [APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/87466/243)