# Converting block to widget after magento update

Tags: blocks, upgrade, widgets, ce-1.9.2.2

A few days back I updated a magento shop from version 1.7 to 1.9.2 . I quickly realized that I had to convert all the old `{{block }}` shortcodes to widgets. This worked fine except for one case:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_featured" name="product_featured" as="product_featured" template="catalog/featured_pers.phtml}}
```

I can not figure out how to get this working in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the helpful Magerun commands https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons

- n98-magerun dev:template-var - Find non-whitelisted vars/blocks to be compatible with SUPEE-6788 and Magento 1.9.2.2
- n98-magerun.phar dev:old-admin-routing - Find extensions that use old-style admin routing (which is not compatible with SUPEE-67

Answer (score 0):

> I quickly realized that I had to convert all the old {{block }} shortcodes to widgets

This is not necessary and won't work for all types of blocks (as you realized). What actually happened is that each **block type** used in `{{block}}` directives must be whitelisted first, for security reasons. This can be done in the admin panel under *System > Permissions > Blocks*.

See also: [APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87974)