# Custom block/template into cms WYSWIYG editor

Tags: blocks, cms

I have problem with inserting custom block/template into cms page editor. If I put the below code to header.phtml it works fine and it displays content inside home page:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('company_slider/slider')->setTemplate('company/slider/slider.phtml')->toHtml();
```

But if I try to insert this into cms page it won't display anything:

```
{{block type="company_slider/slider" name="slider_slider" template="company/slider/slider.phtml"}}
```

I have these lines in extension config file:

```
<global>
      <blocks>
          <company_slider>
              <class>Company_Slider_Block</class>
          </company_slider>    
      </blocks>                                      
</global>
```

Am I missing anything? I guess paths are correct because it works if I insert block directly to phtml file as shown above.

Comment: magento version? you are working on

Comment: version 1.8.0.0

Comment: any error in error log?

Comment: did you check with `{{block type="core/template" name="slider_slider" template="company/slider/slider.phtml"}}`

Comment: This displays template, but block company_slider/slider is not loaded, I need also company_slider/slider to be loaded.

Comment: did you check the error log for errors?

Comment: yes, no errors and error reporting is enabled

Comment: Check in var/log folder

Comment: Yes I did, no errors were there. I just solved the problem, see the accepted answer for details. Tnx anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you added the block in white list?

- Login to admin panel then go to System > Permissions > Blocks
- Add the block - Enter company_slider/slider
- in the field Set Allowed to Yes

Comment: I added company/slider_slider but no difference.

Comment: you mean company_slider/slider right?

Comment: yes, my mistake. I added company_slider/slider

Comment: I just realized that actually solved the problem, I am not sure why it didn't work immediately when I added block into permissions, but it is indeed that what it solved the problem. Thank you! I will whitelist my block inside installation script [(instructions here)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables)