# Set new template file in XML based on other template

Tags: layout, template, xml

I created a new template file, where I placed some custom code, that I want to load inside a page.

I created a CMS page where I load the template file by using:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="/aw_blog/share.phtml"}}
```

I need to use the same php code as the default template file, so I need to define the template by: `<?php $post = $this->getPost();?>`

The default template file is defined inside the XML file like:

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/post" name="post" template="aw_blog/post.phtml">
            <block type="blog/product_toolbar" name="aw_blog_list_toolbar" template="aw_blog/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="blog/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

So I edit the XMl file:

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/post" name="post" template="aw_blog/post.phtml">
            <block type="blog/product_toolbar" name="aw_blog_list_toolbar" template="aw_blog/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="blog/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="blog/post" name="post" template="aw_blog/share.phtml">
            <block type="blog/product_toolbar" name="aw_blog_list_toolbar" template="aw_blog/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="blog/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

But that does not work, because that breaks down the page. It does not load the default content anymore.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use same block type in directive. Instead:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="/aw_blog/share.phtml"}}
```

use:

```
{{block type="blog/post" template="/aw_blog/share.phtml"}}
```

If you need to customize block behavior, then make a custom module with a block extending from blog one and use it in layout and template.

You will have to add the block type to the block whitelist that has been introduced in Magento 1.9.2.2 (and with a security patch for older versions), otherwise it will not be displayed. See [APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but in that case the total block is not displayed inside the page.

Comment: Is the first slash needed ? Never seen that before, it's usually just `aw_blog/share.phtml`

Comment: The slash is unnecessary but should not do harm. The problem is block whitelisting, see updated answer.