# What is the best practice to get rid of CMS blocks getting disappear after patch installation

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

When CMS blocks get disappear after patch installation we normally do is:

> - System > Permissions > Blocks
> - Add New Block
> - Block Name: cms/block
> - Is Allowed : Yes

I feel it's a tricky quick fix. So, i am wondering if there are any other best practices to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to create a `custom installer`.
  (https://www.sitepoint.com/magento-install-upgrade-data-scripts-explained/)
- On this installer you need programcatilly to `admin_block` table using
  `Mage::getModel('admin/block')` model.

> ```
> $whitelistBlock = Mage::getModel('admin/block')->load('catalog/product_featured',
>   'block_name');
>               $whitelistBlock->setData('block_name', 'catalog/product_featured');
>               $whitelistBlock->setData('is_allowed', 1);
>               $whitelistBlock->save();
> ```

If you want more details about this issue please refer to the question below.

[APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87974#87974)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a trick

For security reasons in security patch magento introduce this feature in security pathch `SUPEE-6788`.

so after applying this seacurity patch you have to do whiltlist your block types that you gonna use in  `cms-block` or `cms-page`.

This concept introduce  after this security patch so this is not a trick.

this is the proper way to doing this.